# Difference between Dynamic variables and CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, common-table-expression

What is the difference between using Dynamic variables and CTE(common table expressions)

Dynamic:

```
 DECLARE @id nvarchar

 SET @id = ( SELECT ID_CHIMQ 
 FROM Table1
 where Name = 'Ben')

 EXEC sp_executesql @id
```

CTE:

```
 WITH cte (Col1, Col2, Col3)
 AS
 (
 SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
 FROM Table
 )

 SELECT * FROM cte
```

What is the difference between these two in terms of when you would use one over the other and performance issues etc?

thanks

Comment: Difference is first one will not work and second one will

Comment: @Pரதீப் did i get the code wrong?

Comment: Even if they work,I don't see why the comparison between those two queries is valid.Both are entirely different

Comment: @RyanGadsdon - Yeah wrong, first query will not even execute. Also you cannot really compare dynamic query with CTE. Dynamic is used to generate the queries dynamically and execute it. CTE is used for different purpose.

Comment: @Pரதீப் what is CTE used for?

Comment: A CTE is simply a sub-query.  ;with CTE as (select * from table) select * from CTE is the same as select * from (select * from table) a...
I use CTEs for organization and conciseness of code.

Comment: If we are to be helpful and help you learn, the question is, what makes you think the two queries are similar enough to be compared?

Comment: Dynamic can build SQL statement runtime, for example you can specify table name .. with a parameter.